# Unhide div using javascript object oriented

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i am having trouble unhiding a div, once it has been hidden.

The code:

First object

```
$('#filter_region').on('change', function(e) {

      var temp_region_id = $('#filter_region').val();

      filterRegionId($temp_region_id);

   });
```

Seconds object:

```
function filterRegionId(temp_region_id)
{

    if ($(temp_region_id) != 1) {


       $('.showheadline').hide(); }

    else { $('.showheadline').show(); }

}
```

Really what i want to do, is once the region is changed from the original, the div should be hidden - this works!

However, once the person goes back on the same region, the div is still hidden.

The filter_region echos from 1-8 depending on the region. I realise that i have set the region to 1, this is to test. However, even if the if-statement is set to 1, it still shows the divs when loaded, even if the region is 2-8. Hope this make any sense at all! Please feel free to ask if there are any questions regarding my explanation.

Best Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't parse int value to jquery?
 `if (temp_region_id != 1) ...`
Oh, also check your value, it may be a string. So, I suggest, the right one is `if (temp_region_id != '1')`

Comment: In order for the show block to execute your `temp_region_id` has to be equal to 1.
are you sure `temp_region_id` has the value of 1.

Comment: by parsing the int with jQuery, you are effectively wrapping it in an array, so it should never equal 1, so the headline will always be hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A text input's value attribute will always return a string. You need to parseInt the value to get an integer**

```
 var temp_region_id = parseInt($('#filter_region').val(),10);
```

**and remove the `$` from variable name**  `filterRegionId($temp_region_id);` and `if ($(temp_region_id) != 1) {`

---

```
$('#filter_region').on('change', function(e) {
      var temp_region_id = parseInt($('#filter_region').val(),10);
      ///parse it to integer
      filterRegionId(temp_region_id);
   });
```

---

```
function filterRegionId(temp_region_id){
    if (temp_region_id!= 1)
       $('.showheadline').hide();
    else
       $('.showheadline').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, without the $(..) around the var

```
$('#filter_region').on('change', function(e) {    
     var temp_region_id = $('#filter_region').val();    
     filterRegionId(temp_region_id);
 });

function filterRegionId(temp_region_id)
{    
    if (temp_region_id != 1) {        
       $('.showheadline').hide(); 
    }    
    else { 
       $('.showheadline').show(); 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to rewrite you code a little.
Please add the `filterRegion` function on top and change the parametter name as follows

```
 var temp_region_id = $('#filter_region').val();
 filterRegionId(temp_region_id);
  $('#filter_region').on('change', function(e) {
  temp_region_id= $('#filter_region').val();
  filterRegionId(temp_region_id);
   });

function filterRegionId(temp_region_id)
{
if ($(temp_region_id) != 1) {
   $('.showheadline').hide(); 
}
else { 
     $('.showheadline').show(); 
   }
}
```